AggregateError - npm run - Angular Jhipster
I setuped the Jhispter application with spring boot + angular . The issue is that when ever i try to run the fronent applicationstand alone by using npm run command then its giving me AggregateError. Help me to resolve this error.
I tried decrease in node js version it it would not effective.

Do you have more information about this error? Like a stack trace or something? Also can you show the content of the npm command that you are running?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

src_main_webapp_app_entities_entity_routes_ts.js          | entities-entity-routes          | 910 bytes |
Build at: 2024-10-24T09:55:32.319Z - Hash: 947e3e9fec84a5b4 - Time: 29211ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
√ Compiled successfully.
AggregateError
PS C:\workspace\iscc-microservices\src\main\webapp\app>

these were the stack trace

What version of Node are you using? JHipster 8 requires Node 20.

I am using Node v20.18.0
